# Trying to create a function that creates a discord Embed but am coming up with no luck

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I'm trying to create a function that creates a discordjs embed, then returns it so it can be sent, however, I'm being met with a big problem. Here is a snipped of the error I got

ValidationError: Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead
validator: 's.object(T)',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    given: 'Moon Wolf'                                                                                                                                                                                                                         }

So heres a snippet of the code

```
    let Discord = require('discord.js');
    let nullEmbed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(`#${color}`)
    .setAuthor(username.username)
    .setThumbnail(userURL)
    .setDescription(`${message}`);
    
    return nullEmbed;
}
```

So am I even able to do this in a function or would I have to do it manually throughout each block?

Note: username is the object message.author and the userURL is the users image url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `setAuthor` needs to be an object and not a string
Example:

```js
.setAuthor({ name: username.username })
```